# How to get yyyy-MM-dd from an Instant object in java 8.?

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I am having an `Instant` object . I would like to get `yyyy-MM-dd` as a string.  How can I achieve it?

```
Instant defaultTime = Instant.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
System.out.println(defaultTime); // print 2021-03-26T00:00:00Z
```

How can I get `"2021-03-26"`?

Comment: What time zone are you looking for the date in? I would call `atZone(...).toLocalDate()` to get the `LocalDate`, at which point it's easy to format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to cast to a `LocalDateTime` and then use `DateTimeFormatter` like

```java
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneOffset.UTC);
String result = ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
```

You can find formatter list [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), or use your own pattern

**Other ways**

As @Holger said in the comments, `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)` produces a formatter that can directly format the `Instant` and can be shared and reused to format a lot of instants.

```
static final DateTimeFormatter INSTANT_FORMATTER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Use like

```
    String result = INSTANT_FORMATTER .format(instant);
```

@Ole V.V. mentioned that converting to `LocalDateTime` as in my first snippet throws away the information about which point in time we had. We can keep that information with us when instead we convert to `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime`. If you want to interpret the date in UTC (as in the previous examples), for example:

```
    String result = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
```

This makes it more explicit that the operation is dependent on the choice of UTC for interpretation.

Comment: Or directly `String result = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC) .format(instant);` without the `LocalDateTime` detour.

Comment: @Holger, nice one

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the alternative. My personal taste is for the more explicit application of time zone in the answer. I would also prefer `ZonedDateTime` over `LocalDateTime`. Or `OffsetDateTime` if UTC is desired. So `defaultTime.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)`.

Comment: @OleV.V. for a single use, it doesn't matter, but `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)` produces a formatter that can be shared and reused, to format a lot of instances.

Comment: @Holger I found that both your suggestion and mine deserved to be kept here, and in particular the pros and cons of each, so I have edited them into the answer. IQbrod, if you don’t like it. please revert my edit.